# Request JSON giving error in JMeter though works in postman

Tags: json, .net-core, jmeter, postman, webapi

I am trying to do a load test for one of my APIs in JMeter. The API works fine when tested in swagger or in postman. It gives the correct result. However, when I am trying to call the same API in JMeter, it is throwing following error-

> "errors":{"$.catIds[0]":["The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List`]

Below is my request JSON (using the same in postman where it works perfectly)

```
  {
      "StdFilterParams": {
            "name": "Anna",
            "grade": "V",    
            "schedules": [
                 0
            ]
       }, 
       "SubList": {
           "startTimes": [
               "0"
           ],
           "endTimes": [
               "101010"
           ]
       },
       "catIds": 
       [
          4001
       ]  
 }
```

Here, it doesn't allow me to run the request with this JSON with catIds =4001. My question is what is wrong with this request even if it works in postman.

Comment: Do you send also Content-type header with application/json?

Comment: Yes @user7294900 I have already set it in JMeter

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're sending the same request in JMeter as in Postman?

For example there is a popular mistake that people forget to add [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header via JMeter's [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

In general if request works in Postman you can just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

1. Start [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. If you're using [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) protocol - [import JMeter's self-signed certificate into Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/)

   [image]
3. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/proxy/)

   [image]
4. Run your request in Postman
5. JMeter will capture the request and generate the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and the HTTP Header Manager

[More information:](https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling) How to Convert Your Postman API Tests to JMeter for Scaling

Comment: Yes @Dmitri T, I have Http Header manager added in Jmeter with content-type : application/json. Also I am sure I am running the same request in postman and getting correct result.

Comment: One more question I have though, why it works for rest of the collections (startTimes, endTimes) and complains only for catIds